# Linq2SQL query automatically creates a duplicate database at runtime in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have created update, delete and edit queries in Linq2SQL. Whensoever I run the program it automatically creates a duplicate database of present database and performing changes to it. 
I tried to delete it but whenever program run it creates new database and perform changes to it.

Please help me to solve this problem fast.

Comment: share your query and code

Comment: what version of database are you using, express/localdb/sqlserver ? where is connection string.

Comment: I thought movie stars like you (nice pic btw) don't use words like "whensoever" anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, You have created duplicate database with same name hence whenever you delete the database from server explorer, it get deleted but again start next time it create itself because it get recover data from App code .

So, for this you need to delete App Code showing on solution explorer but of working project. This will ruin the problem of duplication of database next time you start.